# probability of series convergence

Tags: probability

A sequence $(r_n)$ is a result of infinite coin flipping.

Define: $R_n=1$ if $r_n$ is a head and $R_n=-1$ if $r_n$ is a tail.

Is $P(\sum\frac{R_n}{n}<\infty)$ equal $1$ ?

Comment: Yes. Next question?

Comment: What it follows from?

Comment: Tell us. $ $ $ $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $S = \sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{R_n}{n}$, we get $E(S) = 0$, $E(S^2) = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$, so Var$(S)$ converges in $\mathbb{R}$, then $S$ converges in $\mathbb{R}$ almost surely by Kolmogorov's two-series theorem.